# How to sort column names into bins in Pandas Dataframe (Categorical Data)

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I have a Pandas dataframe which includes 173 columns of different college majors (e.g. category_ACCOUNTING) and a value of 1 or 0 in each row below the column to indicate whether the student takes that major or not. I want to sort these 173 columns into two columns - STEM and non-STEM majors. How would I sort categorical data into two categorical bins?

Have tried using pandas.cut() didn't work

[picture of onehotencoded dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeLi1.png)

[edit - I now want to put either '1' or '0' in the STEM and nonSTEM columnsc(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ppmm.png)

Comment: Do yo uwant to order the column which include STEM and non-STEM? Or do you want to create that column according to some mapping?

Comment: @Carsten I want to create a column for STEM degrees and non-STEM degrees and map each degree to either one of those columns :)

Comment: @Carsten i.e. Physics has a value of '1' in the STEM column and '0' in the non-STEM column

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary that creates a mapping:

```
mapping_dict = {'physics': 'STEM'}
df['STEM'] = df['degree'].map(mapping_dict)
```

[I got an error because the column name wasn't accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/drK5E.png)

[image]

Comment: Thank you - as each column is the form 'category_ACCOUNTING' should it look something like mapping_dict = {'category_ENGINEERING: 'STEM'} df['STEM'] = df['category'].map(mapping_dict) ?

Comment: it'll take me a bit to enter each individual major (as there are 173) but I'll get back to you after I'm done. Does the dictionary create two new columns? I wanted two new columns ideally as I'm examining the relationship between STEM and nonSTEM majors and gender so I want to condition on the STEM/nonSTEM columns :) @Carsten

Comment: I got an error because of the column name - it was called 'category'/'category_'. I need to select all columns that begin with 'category_'